# Fixed-Effects Model in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, fitting

I need to fit a model with fixed effects (country and time) to adress the multivariate relation between a dependent variable for 22 countries over 8 years and two independents with the same dimensions.
I am aware of the theoretical purpose of fixed effects to account for time trends and country specific effects but for the life of me I don't understand how I can actually implement it in Mathematica.

I have tried my best to find solutions online but am quite stuck. Really, all I am looking for is a starting point, or better yet an example.

Any help and pointers would be much appreciated!

Thank you very much!
Best,
Ben

Comment: You haven't mentioned the expected error structure (errors independent or serially correlated over time, error variance dependent on country, etc.) but if it's appropriate with your data and objective to have independent errors with a constant variance, countries differing only with intercept or slope, then `LinearModelFit` using the `NominalVariables` option to identify countries should work.  Giving more details about the model to be fit would get you more specific advice.  My point is that all ANOVA functions have specific error structures that need to be identified.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and very helpful reply Jim! I would in fact assume independent errors, so I will try to work with LinearModelFit. Again, thank you very much! I'll see how far I get :)

Comment: Hi JimB, its been a couple of months and I am finally back at this project. Looking through my previous notes and code, I am still stuck. So to take it from the top, essentially I have a y (21 countries, 8 years), x1 (21 countries, 8 years), x2(21 countries 8 years). Looking at LinearModelFit I am unsure how to transpose the data. Also how to account for the difference in years. Perhaps you are still on here and can be my saving grace! :) Best, 
Ben

Comment: If you don't have a particular linear model in mind, then plotting the data to see its structure would seem a good first step.  A 3-D plot of the `{x1, x2, y}` values connected over time for each country might be suggestive.  Without your data and not seeing anything about the subject matter or what you want to do with the predictions in the question makes it hard to suggest something specific.

Comment: There is data on labour-productivity, concentration and robot-density for 21 countries over 8 years. The questions is how concentration measures and robot-density measures can explain labour-productivity outcomes for all of these countries and over 8 years. So the idea is to use a time and country fixed effects model and do a panel regression. In R all this would be relatively straightforward. But for someone as statistically and programming-challenged as me, replicating the logic of the estimation in Mathematica is quite tricky as you can see.

Comment: If you've already run everything in R and the objective is to duplicate in *Mathematica* what you did in R, then giving the R code would seem essential for a successful duplication.  (Not that some of us might agree that what you did in R is what you should be doing.)

Comment: Do you mean that the approach does not make sense to you?

Comment: No.  There are a million ways to do something in R.  If you want something translated to *Mathematica*, you should give the code you wrote in R.  Why should we have to guess as to what you did?  You'll get more accurate answers by supplying what you did.  It also wouldn't hurt to supply either the data or a reasonable facsimile of the data.

Comment: Hey Jim, as the R-code is the result of a research project, I am not comfortable sharing it publicly. Perhaps I could send it to you and we could subsequently post results here so others with similar questions may also find answers.

Comment: Understood.  Unfortunately my available time is limited over the next month so I couldn't do it justice.  Maybe if you could anonymize the data but still have the same structure that would allow many here to get you assistance.